# mouse position in jquery cant be used to move element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this project: http://www.arbamedia.com/test/ but when I drag elements from the **Dyer dhe dritare** menu they jump to the right! somehow this is not working:

```
$(objName).css({"left":left_,"top":top_});
```

it seems to me like it doesn't get the `left_` and the `top_` variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event object `ev` doesn't have `pageX`, `pageY` properties. Instead please use `ev.originalEvent`

```
var left_ = ev.originalEvent.pageX - $("#desk").position().left;
var top_ = ev.originalEvent.pageY - $("#desk").position().top;
```

.

Comment: It is subtracted here it is: 
 var left_ = ev.pageX - $("#desk").position().left;
          var top_ = ev.pageY - $("#desk").position().top;

Comment: I posted it as a general solution. Let me go through your code.

Comment: I removed it but its still not working! I am frustrated I am trying to fix this for 4h now..

Comment: it looks like top_ and left_ dont have any value!

Comment: I updated it now.. but in my console it says:
left_ NaN
top_ NaN

Comment: ok @Diode .. thats what I want. thnx for your help

Comment: You were right. Please check the modified answer. In future please post the part of code in your question.

Comment: Ok thank you. It did the trick I would like to thank you a lot for your time and help.